# Scale all TikZ images in a document by the same factor

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

Is it possible to scale all `TikZ` pictures in a document by the same factor globally?

Something like `\usepackage[scale=0.9]{tikz}` doesn't work.

Comment: You could do `\newcommand*{\ScaleFactor}{0.9}%` in your preamble, and wherever you have a `tikzpicture` use `\providecommand*{\ScaleFactor}{1.0}%`, (so that they can compile by themselves if needed), and use `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\ScaleFactor]`.  Or to automate thie even further, redefine the  `tikzpicture` environment to automatically apply the `ScaleFactor` if it is defined.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every `tikzpicture` uses the style `every picture`. So if you put `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={scale=0.9}}` near the start of your document, all `tikzpicture`s will be scaled by that amount (in addition to any `scale`s you might already be applying to individual `tikzpicture`s).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={scale=2}}
First picture:
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node [transform shape,anchor=base, draw] {Node 1};
\end{tikzpicture}

Second picture: 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node [transform shape,anchor=base, draw] {Node 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If everything in all pictures should be scaled, I would apply the `transform shape` also globally (e.g., `every node/.append style={transform shape}`)

Comment: @Daniel: Good point. Personally, I wouldn't want that, though. For me, one of the great things about creating figures right within the document is that the text size always matches that of the document exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants that the text scales too, one can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\scalefactor}{0.8}

\NewEnviron{mytikz}[1][]{
\scalebox{\scalefactor}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[{#1}]
\BODY
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}

First picture:
\begin{mytikz}[baseline]
\node [transform shape,anchor=base, draw] {Node 1};
\end{mytikz}

Second picture: 
\begin{mytikz}[baseline]
\node [transform shape,anchor=base, draw] {Node 2};
\end{mytikz}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why use a `\scalebox` and not just pass the `scale=` option to `tikzpicture`? Also, using `\scalebox` will result in the text being scaled which is not usually desirable. Also, you could just redefine the `tikzpicture` environment to apply the `scale=` option.